# Cloudinary upload pdf max width and height

Tags: node.js, pdf, cloudinary

Using Cloudinary, just like an image, I would like to limit the width and height of the pdfs that are uploaded.
This is how I upload the file:

```
 const res = await new Promise((resolve, reject) =>
    {
        let cld_upload_stream = cloud.upload_stream(
            {
                folder: process.env.CLOUD_FOLDER,
            },
            function (err, res)
            {
                if (res)
                {
                    resolve(res);
                } else
                {
                    reject(err);
                }
            }
        );

        streamifier.createReadStream(file.data).pipe(cld_upload_stream);
    });
    return {
        url: res.url,
        location: res.public_id
    }
```

Are there any options to limit the width and height, that can work on pdf files?

I tried:

```
{ responsive_breakpoints: 
    { create_derived: true, 
      bytes_step: 20000, 
      min_width: 200, 
      max_width: 1000 }}
```

but it deos not seem to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The responsive breakpoints feature you mentioned is related to analysing an image and deciding which sizes you should resize it to for a responsive design, balancing possible problems if you choose the sizes manually (which are that you may create 'too many' images with very similar sizes, or have large gaps between the byte sizes of the different sizes, so more bandwidth is used than necessary for often-requested files.)

There's a web interface here that uses that feature and provides examples of what it does:https://www.responsivebreakpoints.com/

This is not related to validating uploaded files or editing the original assets that you upload to Cloudinary. There's no server-side validation available related to the dimensions of an uploaded file, but you could either:

- Use an Incoming Transformation to resize the asset before it's saved into your account: https://cloudinary.com/documentation/transformations_on_upload#incoming_transformations
- Use the upload API response after the file is uploaded and validated, and if it's "too big", show an error to your user and delete the file again.

  - You could also use a webhooks notification to receive the uploaded file metadata: https://cloudinary.com/documentation/notifications